# How to obtain the next element in Tao's Theory of the Elements with ternary operator?

Tags: java

I'm a university student learning the ropes of programming and this semester I have to learn Object-oriented Programming. The teacher/engineer barely tells us anything besides what our assignments are and I haven't found any clues on the web. the work sheet says the following: "in java, using the ternary operator, obtain the next element in the theory of the elements, as such - "water generates wood, for example". first there's an input to be asked of the user and the program must check if the input element is valid with an "if" statement and with the ternary operator, indicate the element which is generated from the one scanned. I have at least half the code but I'm clueless about the ternary operator part, I know how it works and how I should build it syntax-wise but not how to work with it properly. here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P04OpTernário {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Choose an element");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String element = in.next();

        if (!element.equals("Fire") && !element.equals("Metal") && !element.equals("Water") && !element.equals("Wood")
                && !element.equals("Earth")) {
            System.out.println("Element does not belong in Tao's Theory of the Elements");
        }
    }
}
```

what I don't know is what to put in the ternary operator test condition, I've tried a few methods and none of the work as needed. suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think a ternary operator as a replacement of `if-else` syntax. Try to write the code as `if-else` block, then translate them to the ternary format like this:

```
String nextElement = element.equals("Fire") ? "Metal" : (element.equals("Metal") ? "Water" : ...);
```

Comment: this is very elucidating of how a ternary operator works but upon trying it, I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. it was a serious push forward in every case so I couldn't thank you more

Comment: I tried this again and I get an error: "failed to convert from boolean to string; string literall is not properly closed by double quotes" what am I missing here? here's the code: 

    String elemGenerated = element.equals("Fire")? "Fire generates Earth" : element.equals("Earth")? "Earth generates Metal" : element.equals("Metal") ? "Metal generates Water" : element.equals("Water") ? "Water Generates Wood" : element.equals("Wood")? "Wood generates Fire" : element.equals("Fire");

Comment: @TwistedMaze `element.equals("Fire")` should be replaced by a `String`.

Comment: it was working but suddenly eclipse gave me a "Value of variable is not being used" did I miss anything? here's what I had:

    else{
   String elemGenerated = element.equals("Fire")? "Fire generates Earth" : (element.equals("Earth")? 
     "Earth generates Metal" : element.equals("Metal") ?
       "Metal generates Water" : element.equals("Water") ?
         "Water Generates Wood" : element.equals("Wood")? 
           "Wood generates Fire" :"Error");
   }
  in.close();

Comment: @TwistedMaze That just means variable `elemGenerated` is not been used  .

Comment: @TwistedMaze It would be nice if you upvote/accept this answer if it helped you:).

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot and carried on with my work, there you go, accepted as answer. if we were to be fair, yours and mr. Boddington up there did the trick but I refered to yours the most.thank you so much for the input :D

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator can be used as follows

```
String nextElement = "Fire".equals(element) ? "Earth" : "Metal";
```

This means that if `"Fire"` is the element, the next element is `"Earth"`, otherwise the next element is `"Metal"`.

This gets the answer right for `"Fire"` but not for other elements. You can make it work for another element by nesting the ternary operator. For example, this works for both `"Fire"` and `"Earth"`:

```
String nextElement = "Fire".equals(element)  ? "Earth" :
                     "Earth".equals(element) ? "Metal" : "Water";
```

By nesting more and more ternary operators like this you can get it to work for all 5 elements. I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

With Java8, a simple switch-case statement would be much easier.

```
switch (nextElement) {

   case "Fire":
      ..blah blah blah...
      break;

   case "Earth":
      ..blah blah blah...
      break;
.
.
.
   default:
      System.out.println ("Element does not belon in Tao's Theory of the Elements");
      break;
```

Of course, if all you care about is making sure it's either one or the other, the cases could be all together with one block of code.

Comment: that looks indeed much easier than using a ternary operator and I would've done it since I have to test for an element and have it print out the sentence "this element generates that element" but I have messy instructions to follow. nevertheless thank you sir, it's very appreciated